# Seven segments anchors, how to use them?

Tags: circuitikz

I had a hard time figuring this one out so I thought I may ask my future self about how to use the seven segment anchor points in Circuitikz.

In the document this is all I find on the topic:

[image]

Comment: Well, the real answer is "...as any other Ti*k*Z anchor: https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.5.1" ;-)

Comment: Ah, but I had a problem finding it and thus this post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is how you do it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[seven segment bits=0011101 dot off box off](segment){}; %give your node a name
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.a) {a}; %you can then refer to them as this
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.b) {b};
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.c) {c};
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.d) {d};
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.e) {e};
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.f) {f};
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.g) {g};
\node [font=\tiny] at (segment.dot) {.};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `\foreach \seg in {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} \node [font=\tiny] at (segment.\seg) {\seg};` is a bit more compact ;-)